# jquery ui spinner not work When using class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, woocommerce, spinner

There is a problem using jquery-ui spinner.

It works normally when using ID.
But for use in the foreach statement,
I have to use the class.

However, it does not work when using a class.
Do you know what the problem is?

my jquery ui version :

1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery( "#spinner" or ".spinner" ).spinner();
});
```

"#spinner" only works.
".spinner" not works.
I don't know what the difference is.

There is a spinner in dev toos.
However, none of the Spinner's text input form, up or down buttons work.
And there is no error in the console.

================================================

```
function get_group_setting() {
  $get_section = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'group_setting');
  if ( $get_section ) {
    echo '<form class="form_group">
        <ul>';
    foreach ($get_section as $field) {
      $values = explode( ' | ', $field );
      echo  '<li><input type="radio" value="' . $values[2] .' " name="select_group" />' . $values[0] . ', ' . $values[1] . ', ' . $values[2] . ' <input class="spinner" name="value_1"></li>';
}
echo    '
        </ul>
    </form>';
}
```

}

Add my for each statement.
thanks.

Comment: `jQuery( "#spinner, .spinner" ).spinner();`

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki I will only use it as a class.
And when using the id, it works normally,
This is the question of why class does not work normally when using the Foreach state.

Comment: Show us the foreach loop

Comment: If you need just class then use `jQuery( ".spinner" ).spinner();`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki ok i know that. but not worked.
I added loop to the question.

Comment: Based on your code it must work like http://jsfiddle.net/o1hqd2e5/4/

Comment: Do you have any error in the console.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yeah, that's what I'm using. There are no errors in the console.
When I use it as an id, it works normally.
I don't think that's why I'm confused.

Comment: There's nothing to be confused about if you've multiple inputs with the same class `spinner`, the code must work, do you've something else that we didn't see here in the posted code?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I think it should work because there is nothing wrong with my script.
but not work.
I don't understand why it doesn't work because I told you everything.

The URL is http://travelsafer1353.cafe24.com/product/2019-%EC%A0%9C2%ED%9A%8C-cc%EC%BB%A8%ED%8D%BC%EB%9F%B0%EC%8A%A4-%EC%B9%B4%ED%85%8C%EA%B3%A0%EB%A6%AC-%EC%B1%94%ED%94%BC%EC%96%B8-%EA%B8%B0%EC%97%85%EB%93%A4%EC%9D%B4-%EC%98%A4%EA%B3%A0-%EC%9E%88/.

Can you take a look?
the spinner outputs are only 2px by 2px points.
I tried to use the size of css but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can see in the console that you've more than 20 error, please try to fix them first.

Comment: No errors are detected in my chrome dev tools console.
Can you show me the error log on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I've solved it.
My problem was the duplication of class names.
I don't want anyone else to do this stupid thing.
I thank those who have tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the below code to make it run:

For both id and class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery( "#spinner, .spinner" ).spinner();
});
```

For id :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery( "#spinner" ).spinner();
});
```

For Class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery( ".spinner" ).spinner();
});
```

Comment: I will only use it as a class. And when using the id, it works normally, This is the question of why class does not work normally when using the Foreach state.